# how to remove a directory entry in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable? (in bash, when the entry is in the middle)

Tags: bash

Suppose my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is now `dir_a:dir_b:dir_c:prj/foo/build:dir_d` or `dir_a:dir_b:dir_c:prj/foo1/build:dir_d`. By using bash script, I want to examin this LD_LIBRARY_PATH and if there is a directory path containing pattern `foo*/build` I want to remove this `foo*/build` part. How can I do it?
If this `*foo*/build` is the last part of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I know I can remove it by `export xx=${xx%:*foo*/build}` but I don't know how to do it if this `*foo*/build` part is surrounded by `:`s.

Comment: You shouldn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all. https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html

Comment: You could disassemble the path by splitting on colons, and then remove that component you want to get rid off, and reassemble the path again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$( tr : $'\n' <<<$LD_LIBRARY_PATH | grep -v YOURPATTERN | paste -s -d : )
```

where YOURPATTERN would be a simple regex describing the component you want to be remove. Depending on its complexity, you may consider the options `-E`, `-F` or `-P` of course.

The `tr` splits the path into segments. The `grep` removes the unwanted ones. The `paste` reassembles.

Comment: I learned a new usage of grep and paste. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | sed 's/foo.*\/build//g')
```

Comment: `sed '...' <<<"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` is typically a bit more efficient than setting up a pipeline (at least if your tmpdir is on tmpfs / otherwise in RAM), and it avoids some correctness problems `echo $variable` has. On that latter count, see [I just assigned a variable. Why does `echo $variable` show something different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: A more serious problem here -- what if there's a `:dir_e/build` at the end of the variable? Matching until `/build` isn't ideal if you can't make it non-greedy (a PCRE extension that `sed` isn't guaranteed to have available).

Comment: Agree. My answer is not meant to be a generic solution, just one that fits this specific question.

Comment: I guess `/` is matched by `*` in the question `foo*/build`. So `/bar` is matched by `*`. Well... useless discussion.

Comment: This also works but chose another answer just because it's more natural and contains new method for me. :). An upvote. Anyway Thanks!